# TYPO3 8, Get error not loaded or no autoloader? Class WapplerSystems\WsFlexslider\Controller\FlexsliderController does not exist

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Added extension folder in `project/web/typo3conf/ext/flexslider` and its working fine at admin site now after add the images in flexslider get error at frontend

```
"not loaded or no autoloader? Class WapplerSystems\WsFlexslider\Controller\FlexsliderController does not exist"
```

Comment: Did you try to clear all caches in the TYPO3 Install Tool? Is your installation composer based?

Comment: Cleared all caches but still get same issue,   I have installed it manually, added flexslider downloaded files in flexslider extension and installed it from extensions tab from admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use typo3 in composer mode?
If so, you have to declare extensions that are not in versioning in the composer.json. Otherwise they wont be added to the autoloader. You can do this the following way:

```
{
 ...
 "autoload-dev": {
   "psr-4": {
    "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Tests\\": "web/typo3/sysext/core/Tests/",
    "Vendor\\ExtensionKey\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/extension_key/Classes/"
   }
 }
}
```

To update the autoloader, the following command must be executed. The additional argument ensures optimization at the same time. The respective classes are loaded faster.

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Answer (score 1):

Put Below code in your typoscript may it can help you!!

```
config.tx_extbase {
 mvc {
    callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
 }
}
```